# Custom fonts get lost in release mode

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have a problem, a bug that I cannot reproduce at all.
In release (Android & iOS), I open the app and I have my nice, ideally wanted fonts.
But often (it may happen after the app coming back from the background (but not always!)) all my fonts become the default and I have completely no idea what it is about.
Fonts are placed in `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts` & `ios/project_name/` (pasted with xCode). This fully works with simulators.

And fonts.ts is

```
export default {
  PoppinsBlack: 'Poppins Black',
  PoppinsBlackItalic: 'Poppins BlackItalic',
  PoppinsBold: 'Poppins Bold',
  PoppinsBoldItalic: 'Poppins BoldItalic',
  PoppinsExtraBold: 'Poppins ExtraBold',
  PoppinsExtraBoldItalic: 'Poppins ExtraBoldItalic',
  PoppinsExtraLight: 'Poppins ExtraLight',
  PoppinsExtraLightItalic: 'Poppins ExtraLightItalic',
  PoppinsItalic: 'Poppins Italic',
  PoppinsLight: 'Poppins Light',
  PoppinsLightItalic: 'Poppins LightItalic',
  PoppinsMedium: 'Poppins Medium',
  PoppinsMediumItalic: 'Poppins MediumItalic',
  PoppinsRegular: 'Poppins Regular',
  PoppinsSemiBold: 'Poppins SemiBold',
  PoppinsSemiBoldItalic: 'Poppins SemiBoldItalic',
  PoppinsThin: 'Poppins Thin',
  PoppinsThinItalic: 'Poppins ThinItalic'
}
```

Comment: We will need some more information than you are supplying here. Unless someone ran into this themselves and recognises the exact situation you describe, there is no easy path for us to help. Even better would be if you could build a small example app (with [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/) for instance) where you are able to reproduce this issue.